# Проверка на существования элемента в отсортированном массиве по индексу

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, поиск, списки

На входе "Х" и отсортированный список. Программка ищет индекс, на который попадет "Х" в отсортированный масив. Всё без использования библиотек, ручками(так надо).

Последняя проверка проходит в следующем цикле:

UPD1. Весь код:

```
x = int(input())  # ввод X
n = int(input())  # ввод кол-ва элементов массива
m = [int(input()) for i in range(0, n)]  # ввод элементов массива
m.sort()
print(m)  # вывод отсортированного списка
index = int()  # для записи индекса, на который встанет Х в список

# сравнение с нулевым элементом
if x < m[0]:
   index = 0

# сравнение с последним элементом
if x > m[len(m) - 1]:
    index = len(m) - 1

j = int(0)
while j != n:
    if x > m[j] and x < m[j + 1]:  # ломается тут. при попытке сравнить "Х" с элементом j+1, которого в списке нет
        index = j + 1
    j += 1

print(index)
```

Он работает как надо, но если "Х" больше, чем последни элемент списка , то ломается и выдаёт: "list index out of range".

Пример входных данных:

```
m = [1, 2, 3]
x = 4
```

Как можно сделать проверку на то, что существует элемент m[j + 1]?

Comment: Приведите для примера весь код, включая массив, пожалуйста. И что конкретно сделать надо?

Comment: Боже мой. Вы скажите, конечная цель какая? В комментарии напишите

Comment: @KitScribe в самом начале ведь написано, что программа ищет индекс, на который встанет Х в отсортированном масиве

Comment: Всё, понял, спасибо. Прошу простить мою невнимательность

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже вы пытаетесь реализовать [`index = bisect.bisect_left(m, x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left), но используете линейный поиск (`O(n)`) вместо [двоичного поиска (`O(log n)`)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA).

Чтобы реализовать (линейный) алгоритм из кода в вопросе:

```
L = [float('-inf')] + m + [float('inf')]  # add sentinels
index = next(i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(L, L[1:])) if a < x <= b)
```

Для примера в вопросе (`m = [1, 2, 3]; x = 4`), получается `index = 3`, что совпадает с ожидаемым результатом: `index == sorted(m + [x]).index(x)`.

Предполагается, что все числа во входном списке `m` больше `float('-inf')` (минус бесконечность) и все элементы в `m` меньше `float('inf')` (плюс бесконечность).

Так как `m` список отсортирован, то существует более эффективный алгоритм, который позволяет найти нужный индекс не сравнивая все элементы (`O(n)` операция), а выполнив [двоичный поиск за `O(log n)` шагов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA), что гораздо эффективней при большом `n` (`n == len(m)`). К примеру, `log10(1000_000) == 6` (приблизительно шесть шагов вместо миллиона -- гораздо лучше).

Иногда приходится руками реализовывать `bisect()`, к примеру, [для последовательностей, у которых индекс может быть больше `sys.maxsize`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32155104/4279):

```
def binary_search(haystack, needle, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(haystack)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if haystack[mid] > needle:
            hi = mid
        elif haystack[mid] < needle:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            return mid
    return hi
```

Пример:

```
>>> binary_search([1, 2, 3], 4)
3
```

Comment: Вот это крутотень!

Comment: `haystack, needle` - оригинально ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input())
n = int(input())
data = sorted([int(input()) for i in range(n)])
index = 0
if x > data[-1]:
    index = n
for i in range(1, n):
    if data[i] >= x > data[i - 1]:
        index = i
        break
print(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему все мои решения давали в какой-то момент неверный результат, поэтому я решил пойти от противного и делать копии списка и использовать классы:

```
class IndexGetter:
    def __init__(self, n, lst):
        self.lst = lst[:]
        self.lst.append(n)
        self.lst.sort()

    def get_index(self, n):
        return self.lst.index(n)


lst = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = IndexGetter(2, lst)
print(lst)
print(x.lst)
print(x.get_index(2))


# тесты
lst = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


_dict = {-1: 4, 0: 5, 18: 11, 15: 11, -7: 0,
         5: 10, 3: 8, 8: 11, 4: 9, -12: 0,
         -5: 0, 6: 11, 1: 6, -4: 1, -9: 0}


for item, result in _dict.items():
    index = IndexGetter(item, lst).get_index(item)
    assert index >= 0
    assert index == result
```

Вот это решение будет работать точно и главное корректно